# Is it possible to run a Buck converter with rectified AC supply voltage?

Tags: ac, rectifier, buck

[image]

I know that a standard Buck converter requires DC voltage as input. But if your primary input supply is a high AC voltage, it is not very easy to make a clear DC voltage out of it. For example, if I use a 3rd order [passive Chebbyshev filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter#Cauer_topology). Even if I put a single capacitor, it won't last for a long time due to high heat dissipation because of its ESR.

Is it okay to not filter this rectified AC voltage and leave it as is? Can the Buck topology work like this?

(Note: Suppose that the load doesn't need very a smooth DC voltage. It can be a lamp or a heater. It requires 15V DC and maximum 30A current. And frequency of the primary input AC voltage is 50Hz.)

Comment: Since it has been rectified, it is no longer AC but DC, albeit a pulsating one. The problem arising from the rapid changes has been dealt with the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bucked off single phase  rectified mains . The filtering on the DC input side was a 16 microfarad metal film cap rated at 630VDc which bypassed the switching frequency but left a rectified sinewave at 100Hz . The output ripple current at 100Hz was high but this was OK for a 1Kw charging application . I also looked at driving a 50mA LED string of 32 white leds using 1 microfarad 400V metal film cap I tested for mains from 180 to 260Vac  YES you can and it makes sense if your output ripple isn't important .Power factor will not be as good as Active PFC but it is much better than a standard cap input filter .A drawback with this approach is that the peak device currents are higher for a given load .

Answer (score 2):

Most switching power supply adapters (such as your cell phone charger) will rectify right off the power line and then use a high voltage capacitor to smooth out the resulting rectified voltage. As long as the smoothing reduces the ripple to a small enough amount then there is no problem for the succeeding buck regulator to operate and produce its designed output voltage.

Some ripple at the input can come through to the output if the output section of the switching regulator is not filtered adequately. For certain you want to make sure that the input capacitor smooths the DCin so that the lowest voltage of the input waveform is still well over the intended output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in the question that concern me so these first: -

- It's not really a problem finding capacitors that are rated at 450V. Plenty easy to find.
- Why would you want to use a Chebyshev filter - this is well over the top and seems almost unconnected with what I read as the "real" question.
- Given the circuit diagram in the question, it makes more sense to use a step-down flyback configuration to reduce ripple currents on the primary AC side. The output voltage required is a maximum of 15V and using a buck converter doesn't make sense to me.

> Is it possible to run a Buck converter with rectified AC supply voltage?

This is possible providing the buck regulator chips internal Vcc is given a chance to stay powered throughout the cycle - this would likely mean a resistor, zener//capacitor voltage dropper to keep the chip "alive". If the chip's logic and control is alive and it can adequately drive the mosfet(s) then I see no-reason why the "power components" of the buck regulator wouldn't be able to cope.